# Cannot scroll to the bottom of container div

Tags: html, css

I see there are other questions with similar titles, but I have not found any satisfactory answers from them.

The problem is that `.content` needs to be 100% of the available view space inside `.container`, but when  `.content` is set to 100% height, is taking up the space equivalent to 100% of the `.container` div causing the bottom most part of it to be hidden, even when scrolled to the bottom.

The reason is because the `.header` pushes down the `.content` div inside of the `.container` div. I am aware of the CSS `calc()` function, but in this particular situation I don't know what the exact height of the `.header` div will be, so need another option.

Here is the code:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    padding: 10px;
    background: dodgerblue;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: ivory;
}

.contentData {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header Title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I figured it out, in case any one else has this problem. By using the `flex: 1;` property, we can make the `.content` div fill only the remaining vertical space. This ensures that any title or top elements will not push the `.content` data out of scrolling reach.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    overflow: clip;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: ivory;
}

.contentData {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

table tr td {
  padding: 100px 50px 100px 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header Title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Etiam imperdiet orci. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.
    </div>
    <div class="contentData">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Etiam imperdiet orci. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Etiam imperdiet orci. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Etiam imperdiet orci. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Etiam imperdiet orci. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Etiam imperdiet orci. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Etiam imperdiet orci. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` from `html, body{}`.
I'm assuming it's behaving like this as you've set `overflow-y: scroll` as well, so the calculatons are a bit wonky.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    padding: 10px;
    background: dodgerblue;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: ivory;
}

.contentData {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header Title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the only problem with that is that now the `.content` div is not scrolling; it is scrolling on the body height; I need the page to be whatever the  body height is, and not scroll the title down, only what's in the `.content` div

Comment: If your div takes up full length and height why would you only want the div to scroll?

Comment: I want the header to remain in place; I do not want the header to scroll with the content or go over the `.content` div. It's for a web application, there are other factors that would take too long to describe here.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to define a percentage of height for your header section and then define an amount that will bring your page height to 97%. Anything more than 97% will force both Edge and Chrome to automatically try to compensate by adding a scrollbar for the page.

```css
.header {
    padding: 10px;
    background: dodgerblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    color: #fff;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 87%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: ivory;
}
```

Depending on the design of your page, you might want to also add a footer. If so, subtract the height from the content section. Remember, you want to throttle the page height to 97% if you don't want the browser to implement a second scrollbar for the page.

Regardless if you have two sections or three, play around with it until it visually looks balanced and appealing. This will give you the professional appearance you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the header have a `position: absolute;` so it does not push down the content. This way your div can take up the full page.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    padding: 10px;
    background: dodgerblue;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: ivory;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.contentData {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    Header Title
  </div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
        <div class="contentData">
      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.

      Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.

      Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat.

      Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.

      Donec mollis hendrerit risus.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it's a good idea, but it causes some of the `.content` div to be covered by the header

Comment: @TK421 I have added margin-top: 40px; so it does not cover the top.